# cx_freeze include_msvcr does not bundle windows VC2015 runtime

Tags: windows, python-3.x, dll, cx-freeze

I am working on building my application on windows with python 3.5.2, I built the python with VC++ Redistributable 2015.24021 installed.

And I don't want the customer to having to install redist themselves, so I figured that cx_freeze include_msvcr option might be the way to go. However, even if I use include_msvcr option, the .exe is still not executable on windows without redist.

I can see there is a VCRUNTIME140.dll which was copied from my built python 3.5.2, and executing it on machines without redist complains about missing api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll.

I can find this .dll file on my build machine, so here are some quick questions.

1. Is it expected that include_msvcr won't bundle dependent .dll files like the abovementioned one?
2. Is there any workaround? Like adding the dll to include_files? Where should I put as destination for the dll?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried to include all the DLLs I can find using Dependency Walker using include_files, but the program still refused to run saying some DLL load failed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just ran into the same problem with Python 3.6 and cx_freeze

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue -- dll was getting copied over, but still getting `VCRUNTIME140.dll missing` error at runtime.

Adding option `'add_to_path': True` fixed it for me.

```
options = {
    'build_exe':{
        'include_msvcr': True,
        'packages':['dde', 'win32ui', 'multiprocessing', 'idna'],
        'add_to_path': True
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the same issue on some of my builds; one build went well and the other didn't.

So after a bit of searching, I found out that adding `import requests` suddenly added `pywintypes36.dll` and `VCRUNTIME140.dll` to the previously wrong build.

No idea why, and I won't say adding this import is a definitive solution, but some packages such as requests seems to ease cx_Freeze's dependency detection.